# When overriding WPF templates do I have to override each theme's template separately?

Tags: .net, wpf, themes, controltemplate

I have a requirement to change a very small part of the WPF ComboBox's template.

If I take a copy of the existing template for the Luna theme and make the change it all works fine initially. But if the user has a different theme, my `ComboBox` retains it's custom theme, (Which is obviously based on Luna) so looks out of place.

Is there any way of overriding just parts of a template so the majority of the template still respects the windows theme?

I notice that parts of the template define an mwt namespace with an explicit reference to Luna:

```
xmlns:mwt="...blah blah...=PresentationFramework.Luna"
```

perhaps there is some way to have this mwt namespace refer to the current theme rather than specifically the Luna one?

Or do I have to provide a custom copy of the template for each theme? And what happens if MS creates a new theme, will I then have to update my template to support it?

(The bit I am changing just relates to the `TextBlock` displayed when the combo box is closed. I'm not changing the dropdown or the button. Ideally I would just override the `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` on the `ComboBox`, but this is readonly, so as far as I can tell I have to override the whole control template to make any changes.)

<sub>[Related question, but no answers: [Adjust a Control Template and still respect the Theme of the OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980055/adjust-a-control-template-and-still-respect-the-theme-of-the-os)]</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One thing to keep in mind is that once
>   you create a ControlTemplate for you
>   control, you are replacing the entire
>   ControlTemplate.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

What I gather from that is no, there is no way to replace portions of a template.  The template is considered a single unit.  However, there may be ways to customize your template to allow changes via styles (which can be based on other styles).

If MS makes a new theme, then you will have to update your own custom control templates to implement a similar theme.  Remember, you're replacing, not enhancing the control template.

Comment: I was worried this might be the case. It seems rather a restriction on the template system. It means there is no way just to tweak a controls look without entirely replacing it. Thanks for pointing out that reference though.